# Propagation delay VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I need to modify the XOR operations used in the parity calculation in such a way that the XOR gates described are each supplemented by a hold time and the propagation delay and use the circuit diagram as a guide.

[image]

For the duration of the hold time, the signal used should be assigned the value "X" (invalid) in the VHDL description, and after the delay time, the new valid signal value.
Note that signal delays are non-synthesisable constructs.

I'm just confused about the delay implementation. Should X(0)/X(1) be stable for 5ns or 8ns ? and X(2) for 3ns or 5ns ?

That's the code I wrote, but like I said, I'm not sure about the delay implementation and would appreciate some guidance.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity parity_gen is
   port( x : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
         y : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
         );
end parity_gen;

architecture sig_handling of parity_gen is
   signal peven: std_logic;
   
    begin
        
   process(peven, x) 
        begin
      peven  <= x(0) xor x(1) xor x(2) after 10 ns;
      if  (x(0)'stable(8 ns) and x(1)'stable(8 ns) and x(2)'stable(3 ns)) then
         y  <= peven & x ; 
      else
         y  <= 'X' & x after 10 ns;
      end if;
    end process;
end sig_handling;
```

Comment: It would help if you named the signals as shown in the diagram. Why do you have both `x` and `X`? What is `peven`? Why do you have both `y` and `Y` and why is `y` 4 bits wide?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's based on a parity generator, so peven is generating an even parity, and the generated bit will be concatenated to the vector x that's why y is 4 bits wide, and for the rest, it's just a mistake that I need to correct

Comment: But the diagram doesn't say anything about concatenation.

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is based on a previous exercise, which is a parity generator. What is required here is the implementation of the delay.

Comment: So the output of a XOR gate shall be `X` for 3 ns after an input change and it shall be the resulting xor value after 5 ns? And what should it be meanwhile (from 3 to 5 ns after an input change)?

Comment: The main issue with these specifications is that the concept of hold time has a clear definition for flip-flops but not for combinatorial logic gates. You should probably ask your teacher what this hold time is.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you for your time. Well I already asked and he said that this is simply the way it is with this task ... I do remember that he said that the exercice was badly thought out

Comment: Well, without a better definition you'll have to interpret. @mkrieger1 gave you a solution based on a literal interpretation of what an hold time is for a flip-flop: if the hold time is violated the output is undefined until the next input change. And I gave you another one, based on a different interpretation: the hold time is the time for the fastest signals to propagate to the output and the propagation delay is the time for the slowest signals to propagate to the output. Pick one or the other (or both to improve your chances of a good grade).

Comment: assignments of the form `output <= 'X' after th, new_value after tp;` should do what you want.

Comment: that's what @RenaudPacalet actually wrote

Comment: I just realized that what I wrote about @mkieger1 code was wrong. If it was using `x(0), x(1)` as sensitivity list for the first process then `c` would always be assigned `X` and never `x(0) xor x(1)`. It would stay stuck at `X` (same for the `y` output). But as it is using `all`, it is the opposite: `c` never takes value `X`. So, this does not behave like a kind of flip-flop with a hold time of `3 ns` and a propagation delay of `5 ns`.

Comment: And so, I added to my answer a solution based on this _flip-flop_ interpretation of the concept of hold time, to show you how you could achieve such a strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a literal translation of the shown diagram as far as I understand it:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity parity_gen is
   port(x : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        y : out std_logic);
end parity_gen;

architecture sig_handling of parity_gen is
   signal c: std_logic;
   
begin        
   process(all) 
   begin
      if (x(0)'stable(3 ns) and x(1)'stable(3 ns)) then
         c <= x(0) xor x(1) after 5 ns;
      else
         c <= 'X' after 5 ns;
      end if;
   end process;

   process(all) 
   begin
      if (c'stable(3 ns) and x(2)'stable(3 ns)) then
         y <= c xor x(2) after 5 ns;
      else
         y <= 'X' after 5 ns;
      end if;
   end process;

end sig_handling;
```

i.e. there are 2 XOR gates which update their output after 5 ns (t<sub>p</sub>), if their inputs have been stable for 3 ns (t<sub>h</sub>), otherwise their output is undefined (my interpretation is that the propagation delay applies here as well).

The inputs to the first XOR gate are `x(0)` and `x(1)`, and the output is `c`; and the inputs to the second XOR gate are `c` and `x(2)`, and the output is `y`.

Comment: It can be that your interpretation is correct (the specifications are really strange) but these XOR gates that indefinitely maintain an `'X'` output after a hold violation, even if the inputs are stable after that, are curious.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet aren't the outputs defined again if the inputs are stable in my model? (I just wrote this off the top of my head and can't simulate it)

Comment: No, after a hold violation, if the inputs don't change again, the outputs will stay stuck at `X`, their last assigned value.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet with `process(all)` it should include the `'stable` signals in the sensitivity list and the output should be updated after the inputs have been stable, shouldn't it?

Comment: @mkieger1 Oh, I didn't see the `all`, I thought it was classical sensitivity lists. This changes things a bit, yes. But anyway, the behavior is maybe not what you expect: each time `x(0)` changes, for instance, the first process resumes and... `x(0)'stable(3 ns)` is false, just because `x(0)` just changed. So `c` will be assigned `X` each time `x(0)` or `x(1)` change. But you're right, `3 ns` later, if the two inputs did not change again, it will be re-assigned with `x(0) xor x(1)`.

Comment: @mkieger1 And, as you are using the default inertial delay in your assignments, and as the second assignment occurs before the delay of the first (`3 ns` vs. `5 ns`), it simply cancels it. `c` never takes value `X`. I am not 100% sure but I think that your first process is indeed equivalent to concurrent assignment `c <= x(0) xor x(1) after 8 ns;`. Not 100% sure because I have never been fully comfortable with the signal assignments algorithms. So I may be wrong.

Comment: @mkieger1 By the way, I just realized that my first understanding of your code was wrong: if you were using `x(0), x(1)` as sensitivity list of your first process, and the same process body, `c` would always be assigned `X`, never `x(0) xor x(1)`. So, this would not behave like a true flip-flop, it would behave as an `X` generator.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: added the *flip-flop* interpretation of the concept of hold time.

There is something strange with your specifications: the output of a XOR gate shall be `X` for `3 ns` after an input change and it shall be the resulting xor value after `5 ns`. But what should it be meanwhile (from `3` to `5 ns` after an input change)? So, there must be something wrong and/or missing.

Something else is missing in your specifications: what should happen when the inputs change again before `3 ns` or `5 ns`? Shall we use inertial or transport delays?

There are two interpretations that I can think of. The first one is quite strange but let's have a look at it: your XOR gates behave a bit like flip-flops. When their inputs change, if it is less than `3 ns` after a previous change, they output `X` (after `5 ns`), else, if it is more than `3 ns` after a previous change, they output the xor of the inputs (after `5 ns`). This is the classical interpretation of a hold time. Modelling this is a bit tricky (because there is no clock to use as a time reference), but doable:

```vhdl
entity myxor is
  port(a, b: in  std_ulogic;
       c:    out std_ulogic
  );
end entity myxor;

architecture beh of myxor is
begin
  process(a, b)
    variable t: time := 0 ns;
  begin
    if t = 0 ns or now - t >= 3 ns then
      c <= a xor b after 5 ns;
    else
      c <= 'X' after 5 ns;
    end if;
    t := now;
  end process;
end architecture beh;
```

Note: there are variants of this interpretation where `c` is assigned `'X'` with a `3 ns` delay instead of `5 ns`, or no delay at all. Modify the code if you prefer one or the other.

And then, for your parity module:

```vhdl
entity parity is
  port(x: in  std_ulogic_vector(0 to 2);
       y: out std_ulogic
  );
end entity parity;

architecture str of parity is
  signal c: std_ulogic;
begin
  u0: entity work.myxor
    port map(
      a => x(0),
      b => x(1),
      c => c
    );
  u1: entity work.myxor
    port map(
      a => x(2),
      b => c,
      c => y
    );
end architecture str;
```

But this kind of mixture between a flip-flop and a XOR gate is so strange that another, maybe a bit more logical, interpretation could be the following: the hold time is the time for the fastest signals to propagate to the output and the propagation delay is the time for the slowest signals to propagate to the output. So, when the inputs of your XOR gate change, the output does not change for `3 ns`, then it takes value `X` from `3 ns` to `5 ns`, and then the xor result. With the default inertial delay(*) you could simply use something like:

```vhdl
entity myxor is
  port(a, b: in  std_ulogic;
       c:    out std_ulogic
  );
end entity myxor;

architecture beh of myxor is
begin
  c <= 'X' after 3 ns, a xor b after 5 ns;
end architecture beh;
```

(*) If your interpretation of these specifications is more oriented towards transport delays, just modify the signal assignments accordingly:

```vhdl
architecture beh of myxor is
begin
  c <= transport 'X' after 3 ns, a xor b after 5 ns;
end architecture beh;
```